# Self Join SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, self

a few days ago I asked for a solution to a SQL query i needed to work out, my data looks like:

```
meta_id post_id     meta_key    meta_value
269     4   _apais               USA
270     4   _aciudad             New york
271     4   _aservicio           Pleasure

...
272     43  _apais               USA
273     43  _aciudad             Chicago
274     43  _aservicio           Fun
...
275     44  _apais               USA
276     44  _aciudad             Miami
277     44  _aservicio           Night Life

278     45  _apais               USA
279     45  _aciudad             Miami
280     45  _aservicio           Sports
```

What i need to do, is to display all the registers that matches Country with City and Service . Or order all the _aciudad registers by country (and _aservicio As service), something like:

```
meta_id     post_id     meta_key    meta_value  meta_key    meta_value  meta_key  meta_value
270         7           _apais          USA     _aciudad    New York   _aservicio Pleasure
261         13          _apais          USA     _aciudad    Chicago    _aservicio Fun
276         4           _apais          USA     _aciudad    Miami      _aservicio Sports
```

@Ravi Gummadi Gave me a solution that looks like this:

```
SELECT t1.meta_id, 
           t1.post_id, 
           t1.meta_key, 
           t1.meta_value, 
           t2.meta_key, 
           t2.meta_value 
    FROM th_postmeta t1, th_postmeta t2  
    WHERE t1.post_id = t2.post_id 
    AND t1.meta_key = '_apais'
    AND t2.meta_key = '_aciudad'
    ORDER BY t1.meta_key
```

That query returns this:

```
meta_id     post_id     meta_key    meta_value  meta_key    meta_value
270         7           _apais          USA     _aciudad    New York
261         13          _apais          USA     _aciudad    Chicago
276         4           _apais          USA     _aciudad    Miami
279         10          _apais          USA     _aciudad    Miami
```

How can I acchive to show only the records that are not duplicated in the meta_value value (for _aciudad and _aservicio only, _apais can be duplicated)?

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Which row would you like to keep?, what is the criteria for this?. On your example, I could choose `meta_id` 276 or 279.

Comment: I need to show _apais, _aservicio, _aciudad and _aciudad must be DISTINCT (his value can't be repeated)

Comment: yes, I understood that. But when `a_ciudad` **is** duplicated, you need to choose one record. What is the criteria for this?, since they will be on different `post_id`

Comment: @Alberto - Your comment makes no sense to me. _apais, _aservicio, and _aciudad are data values, not the names of your columns. Out of this list - meta_id, post_id, meta_key, meta_value, meta_key, meta_value - which values do you need? Perhaps give is an example of what the output *should* look like?

Comment: @Lamak, For each post_id would never be more than one _aciudad, _aservicio, _apais. And there's no criteria really, this is just for generating a list of the _aservicios that are availiable on the db. Any criteria would work i guess, as it don't repeat the listed values.
@Joshua Carmody there's an expable in my original comment of how should the output look, thanks to both of you!

Comment: @Alberto - can you post your expected results?  you show us what the query IS returning to you....how would you LIKE it to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you will end up with more than 1 row with the same meta_value. You want to discard some of these rows, even though they have different values for other fields? In SQL Server you might do something like:

```
SELECT
    ..., x = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY meta_value ORDER BY meta_id )
WHERE
   x <= 1
```

This introduces another calculated column (x) with an increasing number for each row  (order by) restarting on each meta_value (partition by). The `order by` clause defines which ones are most important to keep/discard and the `where` is how many of each you keep.

```
meta_id     post_id     meta_key    meta_value  meta_key    meta_value   x
261         13          _apais          USA     _aciudad    Chicago      1
270         7           _apais          USA     _aciudad    New York     2
276         4           _apais          USA     _aciudad    Miami        3
279         10          _apais          USA     _aciudad    Miami        4
280         10          _apais          ABC     _aciudad    Miami        1
281         10          _apais          ABC     _aciudad    Miami        2
```

I realize you tagged it MySql. I don't really use MySQL and hope this just gives you a clue for something new to Google. Perhaps:

[ROW_NUMBER() in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the meta_id and post_id, you could just delete the text `t1.post_id,` and `t1.meta_id`, and then change `SELECT` to `SELECT DISTINCT`.

If you *do* need the post_id, you'll need to tell us how to decide which row to keep - either meta_id=276 or meta_id=279 - as Lamak noted in his comment above.

**Edit 1:**

If you want to keep meta_id and post_id in the query, but you don't care about which values from meta_id and post_id get kept, then you can do this:

```
SELECT
    MAX(t1.meta_id), 
    MAX(t1.post_id), 
    t1.meta_key, 
    t1.meta_value, 
    t2.meta_key, 
    t2.meta_value 
FROM th_postmeta t1, th_postmeta t2  
WHERE t1.post_id = t2.post_id 
AND t1.meta_key = '_apais'
AND t2.meta_key = '_aciudad'
GROUP BY t1.meta_key, t1.meta_value, t2.meta_key, t2.meta_value
ORDER BY t1.meta_key
```

Note that it's possible that you'll get meta_ids and post_ids from different records "blended" together using this method, since it's not guaranteed that the record with the highest meta_id will also have the highest post_id, and vice-verse.

If you don't need the meta_id or post_id and just want the meta_keys and meta_values, you can do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.meta_key, 
    t1.meta_value, 
    t2.meta_key, 
    t2.meta_value 
FROM th_postmeta t1, th_postmeta t2  
WHERE t1.post_id = t2.post_id 
AND t1.meta_key = '_apais'
AND t2.meta_key = '_aciudad'
ORDER BY t1.meta_key
```

If neither of these methods work for you, then you need to give us some additional criteria so we know how to refine the solution for you.

Comment: like this?:

SELECT DISTINCT t1.meta_id, 
           t1.meta_key, 
           t1.meta_value, 
           t2.meta_key, 
           t2.meta_value 
    FROM th_postmeta t1, th_postmeta t2  
    WHERE t1.post_id = t2.post_id 
    AND t1.meta_key = '_apais'
    AND t2.meta_key = '_aciudad'
    ORDER BY t1.meta_key

It still show duplicated rows for the t2.meta_value records :-|

Comment: @Alberto - Ah, right. I forgot about meta_id. You'd need to get rid of that from your select too.

Comment: Joshua, I solved it. It was simpler:

SELECT DISTINCT t1.meta_id, t1.meta_key, t1.meta_value, t2.meta_key, t2.meta_value
FROM th_postmeta t1, th_postmeta t2
WHERE t1.post_id = t2.post_id
AND t1.meta_key = '_apais'
AND t2.meta_key = '_aciudad'
GROUP BY t2.meta_value 

It worked as a charm, thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks a lot Joshua! I used your solution to do a a self join with three fields and worked great!